# Calling varargs function with arguments

Tags: coffeescript, arguments, apply, variadic-functions, args

When I have a function (which I can't change):

```
trigger: (evtType, args...) ->
    # ... find callback based on evtType
    callback.apply(this, args)
```

Is there a cleaner way of calling it and still achieving the same result than this:

```
    open: ->
        @trigger.apply(@, ['beforeOpen'].concat Array::slice.call(arguments, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the splat also works when [calling a function](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

> CoffeeScript provides splats `...`, both for function definition as well as invocation, making variable numbers of arguments a little bit more palatable.

You can use `arguments...`:

```
open: ->
    @trigger('beforeOpen', arguments...)
```

CoffeeScript will convert that to the usual `apply`/`concat`/`slice` ugliness for you.

Comment: Lovely, that is a lot more coffeescriptish in style, thank you!